# How to get session value using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, session

I have a class to deal with session variables. Here is a sample attached:

```
namespace General
{

    public class Session
    {
        public Session()
        {
        }


        public static string UserID
        {
            get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] as string ?? String.Empty; }
            set { HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] = value;  }
        }

        public static string departFlightID
        {
            get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["departFlightID"] as string ?? String.Empty; }
            set { HttpContext.Current.Session["departFlightID"] = value; }
        }

        public static string returnFlightID
        {
            get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["returnFlightID"] as string ?? String.Empty; }
            set { HttpContext.Current.Session["returnFlightID"] = value; }
        }
}

}
```

Now at some point I store the `flightID` in:

```
General.Session.departFlightID = flightID;
```

And at another point I want to retrieve this value using Javascript. I have seen examples here but they won't work (there's no error but they will return `EMPTY`).

Most recent tries:

```
 var session = '<%= General.Session.departFlightID %>';
 var session = '<%= HttpContext.Current.Session["departFlightID"] %>';
```

It does work if I set value on page load, but I am running a webmethod where I create a html and then send that html back to be populated inside a div to make a ticket there. I need to get the session value but it does not update.

To make it more clear here is the Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function addTicket(flightID, flightType) {
    PageMethods.addTicket(flightID, flightType, OnGetMessageSuccess);
}

function OnGetMessageSuccess(result, userContext, methodName) {

    var pageUrl = document.URL;
    if (pageUrl.indexOf("&ret_date=&") !== -1) {

        var session = '<%= HttpContext.Current.Session["departFlightID"] %>';

        alert(session);
        result = result + "<a onclick=\"searchflight.abortAllAjax()\" data-index=\"6\" class=\"bookNow\" title=\"Book Now!\" href=\"#\">Book Now!</a>";
        result = result + "</div>    </div>  </div>";
        document.getElementById("detail").innerHTML = result;
    }

}
```

And here is the webmethod:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string addTicket(string flightID, string flightType)
    {
        //GET FLIGHT DETAILS  FROM DATATABLE OR SESSION DATA TABLE
        string tmpHtml = string.Empty;
        tmphtml="sample";
        string flightID="123123213";
        General.Session.departFlightID=flightID;

    return tmphtml;
    }
```

Comment: have you tried: `var session = '<%= HttpContext.Current.Session["departFlightID"]; %>';` ?

Comment: @karaxuna nope but let me check ...

Comment: yup it did the same returns empty.

Comment: are you writing above script code in aspx file or js file ? if you are writing it in a js file it will not work.

Comment: maybe it's because of static context. try assigning like this: `HttpContext.Current.Session["departFlightID"] = flightID;`

Comment: var user_srno = '<%= HttpContext.Current.Session["user_srno"] %>';
        alert(user_srno);   Works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same Question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818917/is-it-possible-to-a-create-session-variable-in-javascript).

we usually have sensitive data in Session Variables, so they are always server side. Still if you want you can try adding a HiddenField in your .aspx markup and in code behind you can set it . once the value is set, you can very easily access  the value using  $("#id") way or Document.GetElementById() method.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using mvc, then:

```
var ttype = ' @HttpContext.Current.Session["TestType"] ';
```

Answer (score 0):

WebMethods do not support Session variables by default.  Your WebMethod declaration should look like this:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not .