# Access Session Variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I need to access a Session Variable in javascript. I tried all the examples but none of them are working. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

I have the following:

In my Account controller after successful login I set my Session Variable like this.

```
 HttpContext.Session.Add("IsShowStartPopUp", true);
```

In my landing view I try to access the session variable like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 
var IsShowStartPopUp = '<%= Session["IsShowStartPopUp"] %>';

</script>
```

My result is:

> '<%= Session["IsShowStartPopUp"] %>'

Am I missing something?

Thanks you.

Comment: Does this help: [How to get session value using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20672188/6504633)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer:

**No, session state is server-side.**

I then use the following:

I still set the session variable in the controller when the user log in

```
HttpContext.Session.Add("IsShowStartPopUp", true);
```

I then created the following in my MVC view:

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.Session["IsShowStartPopUp"].ToString() == true)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["IsShowStartPopUp"] = false;
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {ShowPopup();}
    </script>
};
```

This solved my issue and if there is any suggestions you are more that welcome to comment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you should not use contention while trying to access a dynamic value **'<%= Session["IsShowStartPopUp"] %>'** . Otherwise, it'll be considered as a string.

You can use **sessionStorage**.

Example:

```
<script> 
sessionStorage.setItem('mysession','value');

alert(sessionStorage.getItem('mysession'));
</script>
```