# How do websites keep you logged in

Tags: javascript, php, html

Quick Question: When you login to your account on a website what does it do to keep you logged in so you don't login again and again when you visit another page?

Comment: Please post details in your question. Are you trying to keep users login to your system for a long days or for all pages? please clear.

Comment: They basically choose cookie expiry date something very far in the future

Comment: Quick answer. You save a token after the first login in the cookie. After that you auth the user again their token. You should set the expire of the cookie to the time you want (e.g. day/week/year)

Comment: A big question!
You need to search.
At first, take à look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818917/is-it-possible-to-a-create-session-variable-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks everyone :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is all about sessions.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science))

> In computer science, in particular networking, a session is a
>   semi-permanent interactive information interchange, also known as a
>   dialogue, a conversation or a meeting, between two or more
>   communicating devices, or between a computer and user
>   Web server session management
>   ...
>   Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) is stateless: a client computer
>   running a web browser must establish a new Transmission Control
>   Protocol (TCP) network connection to the web server with each new HTTP
>   GET or POST request. The web server, therefore, cannot rely on an
>   established TCP network connection for longer than a single HTTP GET
>   or POST operation. Session management is the technique used by the web
>   developer to make the stateless HTTP protocol support session state.
>   For example, once a user has been authenticated to the web server, the
>   user's next HTTP request (GET or POST) should not cause the web server
>   to ask for the user's account and password again. For a discussion of
>   the methods used to accomplish this see HTTP cookie and Session ID
>
> In situations where multiple web servers must share knowledge of
>   session state (as is typical in a cluster environment) session
>   information must be shared between the cluster nodes that are running
>   web server software. Methods for sharing session state between nodes
>   in a cluster include: multicasting session information to member nodes
>   (see JGroups for one example of this technique), sharing session
>   information with a partner node using distributed shared memory or
>   memory virtualization, sharing session information between nodes using
>   network sockets, storing session information on a shared file system
>   such as a distributed file system or a global file system, or storing
>   the session information outside the cluster in a database.
>
> If session information is considered transient, volatile data that is
>   not required for non-repudiation of transactions and does not contain
>   data that is subject to compliance auditing then any method of storing session information
>   can be used. However, if session information is subject to audit
>   compliance, consideration should be given to the method used for
>   session storage, replication, and clustering.
>
> In a service-oriented architecture, Simple Object Access Protocol or
>   SOAP messages constructed with Extensible Markup Language (XML)
>   messages can be used by consumer applications to cause web servers to
>   create sessions.

In raw php (most well known frameworks has session management middleware, so you shouldn't worry about it) if you want to manage a session, you have to include

```
session_start();
```

procedure on top of your pages. When you do this, you are creating a 24 minutes (1440 seconds) session ([by default](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php)).

You can modify it to any integer from your php.ini file.

All session data in php stored in `$_SESSION` global. Hence, it is an array, so you can set session variables (aanything you want) like,

```
$_SESSION['user_name'] = 'ernesto';
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
...
```

At any time of your application, you can remove $_SESSION variables,

```
session_unset();
```

Assume, you've already set variables above,

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

will print empty array as you've removed variables by unset procedure.

If you want completely to destroy a session,

```
session_destroy();
```

will do it for you.

Answer (score 8):

Cookies and Session are some of the traditional ways that authentication details are stored in browser. However through these approaches server has to keep track of logged in users and their cookies to validate. So there is some server operation in managing logged in users. 
 However there's a new approach known as JSON Web Token aka JWT. Here server will generate an user specific token and sends into browser client on logging moment. Browser will store this token in HTML5 Local Storage or Session Storage and will be sending this token with every request! 
So here for every refresh browser code can check for the availability of this token in Local Storage or Session Storage. Advantage of this approach is that the server doesn't have to keep track of issued token and is able to extract data from token if needed. 
 This JWT is widely used in authenticating Web applications developed using advanced Javascript frameworks : Angularjs or Reactjs(with supporting libraries)

Answer (score 5):

Browsers will keep you logged in by using some sort of browser storage. (for example cookies or localStorage or...). This data is called session data.

Html pages are stateless, that means when you refresh a page, all data that came from the server previously, are removed, and have to be requested again.

Now to request a protected page, there has to be a way to tell the server that you are the user that is logged-in a few minutes ago! This is done by storing some encrypted data in browser, usually in cookies.

Browsers are designed in a way that automatically send a specific page's all cookies to server when the page is opened. Server has the exact encrypted data in files or database and compares it with browsers data. if they match, server will allow protected content to get viewed by user, so will send the requested content as response.

you can simply test this by clearing your browser cache after login and then refresh, you will see that you are logged out, and not allowed to see protected page.

Comment: It is discouraged to send a password each time. Instead a token must be sent back when the user logs in and in all future requests that token must be used to validate the session.

Comment: @chetan, thanks for the feedback, you're right, this is an old answer :)
I fixed the username and password part and improved the answer a little bit.

Answer (score -2):

use cookie **you can learn**: [Cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) or Session **you can learn** [Session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)